# Retrieve specific key value pair from nested dictionary within nested list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-lists, dictionary-comprehension

I have below nested list, I want to retrieve only key value pair from this list
i.e - 'ticker': 'ABC 0.737 03/15/23'

```
list = 

[[{'data': [{'figi': 'BBG00ZTHB2X0', 'name': 'AMERISOURCEBERGEN CORP', 'ticker': 'ABC 0.737 03/15/23', 'exchCode': 'NEW YORK', 'compositeFIGI': None, 'uniqueID': None, 'securityType': 'GLOBAL', 'marketSector': 'Corp', 'shareClassFIGI': None, 'uniqueIDFutOpt': None, 'securityType2': 'Corp', 'securityDescription': 'ABC 0.737 03/15/23'}]}], [{'error': 'No identifier found.'}], [{'error': 'No identifier found.'}]]
```

I tried this approach:

```
keys_to_retain = ['ticker']
print([{key: d[key] for key in keys_to_retain if key in d} for d in list])
```

I got below response

```
[{}, {}, {}]
[{}, {}, {}]
[{}, {}, {}]
[{}, {}, {}]
```

Any help in right direction would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your list has always the same structure, you only have to go step by step until you reach the dictionary from which you want to extract the data.

Here is an example:

```
ls = [[{'data': [{'figi': 'BBG00ZTHB2X0', 'name': 'AMERISOURCEBERGEN CORP', 'ticker': 'ABC 0.737 03/15/23', 'exchCode': 'NEW YORK', 'compositeFIGI': None, 'uniqueID': None, 'securityType': 'GLOBAL', 'marketSector': 'Corp', 'shareClassFIGI': None, 'uniqueIDFutOpt': None, 'securityType2': 'Corp', 'securityDescription': 'ABC 0.737 03/15/23'}]}], [{'error': 'No identifier found.'}], [{'error': 'No identifier found.'}]]


def key_to_retrain(key):

    value = ls[0][0]['data'][0][key]
    return value

print(key_to_retrain('ticker'))
```

Output:

```
ABC 0.737 03/15/23
```